# Method calling does not accept char input

Tags: c#

I want to obtain the Unicode code of a certain char. The declared function does not accept the argument.

the code blocks at line `string str01 = GetEscapeSequence(char c1);`

The error:

> Error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `c1', expecting`.' (CS1525)

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace problem_005
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Insert the caracter");
        char c1 = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string str01 = GetEscapeSequence(char c1);

        Console.WriteLine("the Unicode is ={0}", str01);

        Console.WriteLine("m");
        }
        public string GetEscapeSequence(char c)
        {
            return "\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("X4");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call a method in C#, you don't need to specify the parameter type. Just

```
string str01 = GetEscapeSequence(c1);
```

will suffice.

Also, as `main` is a [static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629(v=vs.71).aspx) method, you must make `GetEscapeSequence` static as well:

```
public static string GetEscapeSequence(char c)
```

Comment: in this case I receive the error: " Error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member"

Comment: You must make the `GetEscapeSequence` method static as well.